# django render template does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm using `linux`, `python 3.4`, `django 1.8.2`, `pytmysql`

In my virtualenv there are:

`db.sqlite3`     `manage.py`     `new/`      `templates/`

---

settings.py:

First I commented `'DIRS':[],`

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        #'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
 ]
```

then add this part:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (    
        '/home/niloofar/django/niloofar/new/templates',    
)
```

urls.py:

from new.views import welcome

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^welcome', welcome),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def welcome(request):

    message = "welcome again:D"
    return render(request, 'base.html', {'message': message})
```

In templates directory, there is base.html file:

```
<html>
 <body>
 <p>* {{ message }} *</p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

When I refresh the page it prints error:

> Exception Type:   TemplateDoesNotExist
>
> Exception Value:  base.html

Comment: What is full path of your `base.html`?

Comment: /home/niloofar/django/niloofar/new/templates/base.html

Comment: try $ ls -a /home/niloofar/django/niloofar/new/templates. What do you get?

Comment: Why use `TEMPLATE_DIRS`? This is deprecated since 1.8. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#template-dirs

Comment: here were `.`  `..`  `base.html`

Comment: Instead of commenting out `dirs` try setting it to an array containing the dirs in `template_dirs`.

Comment: yes it worked, was helpful, thanks:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, don't need to comment DIRS. 
The setting TEMPLATE_DIRS is deprecated. see the link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#template-dirs

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..//', 'templates').replace('\\', '/')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: if you think this solution  helped you then approve it with green mark

Comment: That stuff with the replace call is nonsense. Don't do things like that.

Comment: @Sayes thanks for suggestion i have updated my answer